# MVC Custom View Engine FileExists always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to implement a Custom ViewEngine that inherits from `RazerViewEngine`:

```
public class MultiTenantViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MultiTenantViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/Views/%tenant%/{1}/{0}.cstml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cstml",
            "~/Views/%tenant%/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        };

    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        var controller = controllerContext.Controller as MultiTenantMVCController;
        var newViewPath = viewPath.Replace("%tenant%", controller.Tenant.Name);
        var newMasterPath = masterPath.Replace("%tenant%", controller.Tenant.Name);
        return base.CreateView(
            controllerContext,
            newViewPath,
            newMasterPath);
    }

    protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
    {
        var controller = controllerContext.Controller as MultiTenantMVCController;
        var newVirtualPath = virtualPath.Replace("%tenant%", controller.Tenant.Name);
        var exists = base.FileExists(controllerContext, newVirtualPath);
        return exists;
    }
}
```

The ViewEngine class is registered in Application_Start and the `FileExists` method is hit. It now checks if a file `~/Views/Foo/Home/Index.cstml` exists, which it does, but it does return false.

I then get a Yellow Screen of death with the following error message:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The View "Index" ...:
~/Views/%tenant%/Home/Index.cstml
~/Views/Home/Index.cstml
~/Views/%tenant%/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml]
```

Checking the path with

```
System.IO.File.Exists(controllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(newVirtualPath));
```

returns false as well, although if I copy that path and open it in explorer directly it works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: After a reboot it does work now, so this error is no longer reproducable. I'm voting to close.